# AngularJS with own custom router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an existing SPA that I'm migrating to angular 1 view at time.  I can't change the router.  I'm loading a view like this then boot strapping it:

```js
loadView("views/view1.htm", function(view) {
    myDiv.innerHTML = view;
    angular.bootstrap(myDiv, [‘MyApp']);
});
```

Obviously because this is a single page app this only works once.  This need to integrate the the rest of the SPA so myDiv.innerHTML is constantly replaced.

Should I destroy my App each time I switch views? If so how it this done?

Many Thanks

Comment: 1st thing how can you destroy your app each time?

Comment: I don't know how but I guess would do it before I swapped the innerHTML.